# Shape of spot curve Volatility in Hull White 1 factor

Tags: interest-rates, interest

The formula for the volatility of interest rates under Hull white model is

[image]

It appears to be an increasing function of tenor. However, the forward rate volatility curve is downward sloping with maturity.

kindly let me know your valuable thoughts.

Comment: Mean reversion?